# How to run awk script on multiple files

Tags: awk

I need to run a command on hundreds of files and I need help to get a loop to do this:

1. have a list of input files /path/dir/file1.csv, file2.csv, ..., fileN.csv
2. need to run a script on all those input files
3. script is something like: command input=/path/dir/file1.csv output=output1

I have tried things like:
`for f in /path/dir/file*.csv; do command`, but how do I get to read and write the new file every time?
Thank you....

Comment: Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins and do NOT write a shell loop - it is the wrong approach (see for example http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219) and completely unnecessary. If you post sample input and expected output we can hep you. Please change every occurrence of the word "script" in your question to be either "shell script" or "awk script" to make it clear which you are talking about in each statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, (after changing `/path/to/data` to the correct path. Same with `/path/to/awkscript` and other places, pointing to your test data.)

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/data
for f in *.csv ; do
    echo "awk -f /path/to/awkscript \"$f\" > ${f%.csv}.rpt"
    #remove_me awk -f /path/to/awkscript "$f" > ${f%.csv}.rpt
 done
```

make the script "executable" with

```
 chmod 755 myScript.sh
```

The `echo` version will help you ensure the script is going to work as expected. You still have to carefully examine that output OR work on a copy of your data so you don't wreck you base-line data.

You could take the output of the last iteration

```
awk -f /path/to/awkscript myFileLast.csv > myFileLast.rpt
```

And copy/paste to cmd-line to confirm it will work.

WHen you comfortable that the `awk` script works as  you need, then comment out the `echo awk ..` line, and uncomment the word `#remove_me` (and save your bash script).

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in /path/to/files/*.csv ; do
  bname=`basename $f`
  pref=${bname%%.csv}
  awk -f /path/to/awkscript $f >      /path/to/store/output/${pref}_new.txt
done
```

Hopefully this helps, I am on my blackberry so there may be typos

Comment: I'll start with this as it seems simpler...My problem seems to be that the script itself needs to contain input= and output= in the syntax.....so I can not really specify one path. E.g. my script would change from file to file: command input=/path/dir/file1.csv output=output1, then command input=/path/dir/file2.csv output=output2 .....